# How can see ALL devices (including ethernet) connected to Airport Extreme?

Tags: airport

I am running Airport Utility 6.3.  I can see the list of WIRELESS clients connected.  I can't see anywhere in the utility where I can see WIRED/ETHERNET clients connected.

Other posts on this site refer to an Advanced Settings Tab on Airport Utility 6.x. or else Manual Setup.   I don't see this anywhere in the GUI.  Under the Network tab, you can reserve static IPs, but that's not what I want, I want to see which WIRED (not just wireless) devices are actually connected.  I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with my DirecTV box which doesn't seem to be connecting even though I have reserved an IP for its MAC address.  Yes, I can ping the IP, but the point is if I want to set it to DHCP, I wouldn't know the IP, and it would be nice to just see what all the devices are.

Answer (score 10):

There's a great shell command that scans your network on all interfaces that are connected.

The command is `arp -a`.

Comment: That is not how arp works. It does not actually scan the network. This command shows you the mac-addresses that are stored in your arp-table (usually, I would guess, this table would not be a complete list of all devices on your subnet).

Comment: It does so for me, in live-time. If I disconnect a device and rerun arp, the change is noticed immediately, the same goes for connecting a new device.

Comment: to filter out only the connected devices, `arp -a | grep -v "incomplete"`

Answer (score 6):

### [iNet](http://www.inetapp.de)

iNet will scan your network for all connected devices and show you a list of devices with their hostnames and IP addresses. It also has a **dedicated mode for AirPort routers** showing devices connected and relevant information about each one.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The airport utility is for wireless devices.  The Network Utility shows all devices under display routing table information.  The data can be difficult to interpret.

Comment: This is the correct answer, a built-in application native from the OSX system and display all information requested by the user in question.

Comment: Spotlight search (the magnifying glass icon in the top right corner of my display) --> `Network Utility`.  Then select `Netstat` tab, choose radio button `Display routing table information`, then hit the blue `Netstat` button.  It takes quite a while to get results.  The results table does NOT display MAC Addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I can't but wonder why AirPort Utility doesn't let the user not only enlist the connected devices, but also manage them in some way (a black list comes to mind, Forcing a device to reconnect by disconnecting it temporarily, and so on).

Using AirPort Utility 6.3.1 I can only see as a pop-over window, a list of WiFi devices connected to my TimeCapsule - many of which show no name, or device-type. Now I wonder --- Is there some intruder? Maybe a neighbor who cracked my network password?

Or is it just my wife's new iPhone?

And what network those devices are connected to? the "regular" network, or the "guest" network I've set up?

The utility is so short of answers, and of any reasonable control over connected devices. A shame.

Comment: not an answer..

Answer (score 2):

Open the airport utility and press the option key when you open the airport extreme and you will see a summary window on that window you will see all connected devices and some statistics. 
Unfortunately apple has removed the log option actually it has removed all the advanced options in the last version of airport utility... :(

Comment: Alt + Double-click in the AirPort "Device icon" in AirPort Utility worked for me.

Comment: This dialog (as of AirPort Utility 6.3.9, at any rate) still only shows *wireless* clients.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why this is not available by default in Airport Utility 6.x as well. I was able to achieve the same by installing a FREE app called [Fing](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2409870,00.asp). This is available for both Android and iOS devices.

Fing displays devices connected by ethernet as well as ones connected by wifi.

Comment: There used to be a Mac app called Who's On My WiFi, but it's apparently no longer available on the App Store :(